# Grails BootStrap issue

Tags: grails, plugins, dependency-injection, redis

I have an application that uses the Grails Redis Plugin. This plugin works fine and provides a redisService in my Grails Artifacts just fine. I also have a singleton `CacheManager` class that has as a static instance variable, a reference to the `redisSevice`. In `Boostrap.groovy`:

```
class BootStrap {

    def redisService

    def init = { servletContext ->
        CacheManager.instance.redisService = redisService
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}

class CacheManager {

    def redisService

    private static CacheManager manager = new CacheManager()

    private CacheManager() {
    }

    public static CacheManager getInstance() {
        manager
    }
}
```

This works fine for a while, after a while, the `redisService` somehow becomes null. I use this cache manager as a layer above redis. I haven't found a better way to be able to inject a service into a standard POGO, so this works. It just seems to fail after being idle for a while.

Anyone have an idea as to why? Or a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Holders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html) to access `redisService` in `CacheManager` seems to be a better option:

```
import grails.util.Holders

class CacheManager {

    def redisService = Holders.applicationContext.getBean("redisService")

    (...)
```

When your `redisService` in `CacheManager` becomes null? Is it when developing app with reloading classes? Or in 'normally' running app? The first case would be a good explanation on why it becomes null, otherwise I have no idea right now...

Comment: You really shouldn't ever have to use `Holders`. Typically when you find yourself reaching for `Holders` you need to pause and ask yourself "Am I really doing the right thing there?" In your case the answer is No. It should be a spring managed bean, and you shouldn't be using `Holders`.

Comment: I don't think it's the best idea to use Holders, but rather minimal modification to make provided example working. Normally I would rather define `CacheManager` as bean as you suggested in your answer. Anyway, thanks for good explanation and advice :)

Comment: You're more than welcome. Glad to help. Moving the provided example to a Spring managed bean inside `Resources.groovy` would actually cut down on the amount of code (e.g. everything removed from bootstrap, and one or two lines added to resources). :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, defining the `CacheManager` as an actual spring bean inside `Resources.groovy` would be the `best` and `correct` way to do this. Doing so would also likely avoid any issues you are having where the reference becomes `null`.

Comment: Thanks all. I'm still not sure that I have an answer that I can use. My main issue is to get access to my CacheManager from within pogos which are actually Hystrix commands. Therefore no automatic injection. The redisService is a singleton. The CacheManager is also a singletons.

Comment: Darn phones auto correction. The CacheManager is also a Singleton. If I turn it into a Spring managed bean, then how do I get access to it in my Hystrix command object, without using Holders?